# XPath Selecting value of an XML node based on multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

The following XML represents a simplified version of a more complex structure that I am working with. I want to be able to select a specific value based on some meta data.

```
<Root>
    <Data>
        <KeyValuePair>
            <Key>Field1</Key>
            <Value>Value1</Value>
        </KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>
            <Key>Field2</Key>
            <Value>Value2</Value>
        </KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>
            <Key>Field3</Key>
            <Value>Value3</Value>
        </KeyValuePair>
    </Data>
    <Name>Customer</Name>
    <ID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ID>
</Root>
```

I want to be able to select the text of the Value node where the Key node text equals "Field2" and the Name node equals "Customer". I also need to make this flexible enough to not care about namespaces.

I have been able to select the node based off of the sibling node using the following:

```
//*[local-name()='Value'][../*[local-name()='Key'][./text() = 'Field2']]/text()
```

But while searching has yielded results for how to select child nodes based on parent attributes I have been unable to find a solution for my particular dilemma.

I am new to XPath, so I may not be searching for the correct thing or there may not be a solution for what I want. Either way, if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have rephrased my question for clarity, The XML provided is not exactly what I am working with, but a simplified representation of the structure. I have also seen comments about case sensitivity and have edited my code to more accurately reflect the given example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath and remember that XPath is *case-sensitive*:

```
//Value[../Key='Field2' and ../../../Name='Customer']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
/Root[Name="Customer"]/Data/KeyValuePair[Key="Field2"]/Value/text()
```

will select all text nodes of `Value` elements within `KeyValuePair` elements with a `Key` child element whose string value is `"Field2"`, provided that `KeyValuePair` is a child of a `/Root/Data` element with a `Name` child element whose string value is `"Customer"`.

**Notes:**

1. XML and XPath are case-sensitive.
2. Your use of `local-name()` is unnecessarily awkward.  You may have seen
   this technique done elsewhere in an effort to defeat namespaces, which shouldn't be done
   generally, and in particular here is unnecessary because there are
   no namespaces in play.